# LINQ Changeset multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL and after I submit some changes I want to spawn a thread which looks through all the changes and updates our lucene index as necessary. My code looks vaguely like:

```
(new Thread(() => { UpdateIndex(context.GetChangeSet()); }).Start();
```

Sometimes though I get an InvalidOperationException, which I think is because context.GetChangeSet() is not thread-safe, and so if the change set is modified in one thread while another thread is enumerating through it, problems arise.

Is there a "thread-safe" version of GetChangeSet()? Or some way I can do ChangeSet.clone() or something?

Comment: GetChangeSet executes in the calling thread, before calling UpdateIndex with the value it returned, so that problem would only exist if you have the calling thread calling GetChangeSet repeatedly while the created threads are still running, right?

Comment: I think that the issue is not that the calling thread is calling GetChangeSet but that the underlying collection is being modified (the items are being committed to the db, marked as conflicts etc.) This is just a guess though, what actually happens after I call context.submitChanges() is sort of a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance members of the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) class **are not thread-safe**.

In order to avoid race conditions you should invoke the [DataContext.GetChangeSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) method from the same thread that makes the modifications tracked by the DataContext instance. For example:

```
public class CustomerDao : IDisposable
{
    private DataContext context;

    public CustomerDao()
    {
        this.context = new DataContext("SomeConnectionString");
    }

    public void Insert(Customer instance)
    {
        this.context.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(instance);
        this.StartUpdateIndex();
        this.context.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(Customer instance)
    {
        this.context.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(instance);
        this.StartUpdateIndex();
        this.context.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.context != null)
        {
            this.context.Dispose();
        }         
    }

    private void StartUpdateIndex()
    {
        ChangeSet changes = this.context.GetChangeSet();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            state => this.UpdateIndex((ChangeSet)state), changes); 
    }
}
```

This assumes that the Insert and Delete methods are being called on a given instance of the CustomerDao class from a single thread.

Comment: The only time I want multiple threads is just for the StartUpdateIndex() thing; is there any way that I can just copy the change set into a thread-safe structure? I don't need my insert, delete etc. methods to be thread-safe, so I'd like to avoid having to write a bunch of locking code.

Comment: I see what you mean. I updated my answer and removed all locking code on the assumption that only the UpdateIndex method will be run on different threads.

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to extract a small amount of data from each object, so for I ended up just extracting the text, putting it into a new object, then sending that new object off. This saved me a lot of trouble from having to deal with locking everywhere else, but I think Enrico's answer is probably the "real" one, so leaving his marked as the solution.